# When the new version is downloaded, the 'update-downloaded' event is not being triggered

Tags: node.js, electron, electron-builder

I'm new to electron and I have the following problem:

"electron-log": "^2.2.17",
"electron-updater": "^3.1.2",
"electron-builder": "20.14.7",

```
import { autoUpdater } from 'electron-updater';
import log from 'electron-log';

log.transports.file.level = 'info';
autoUpdater.logger = log;

async function autoUpdateConfig() {
  autoUpdater.autoInstallOnAppQuit = true;
  autoUpdater.autoDownload = true;

  // Emitted when there is an error while updating.
  autoUpdater.on('error', (ev, err) => {
    mainWindow.webContents.send('update-info', err);
  });

  // info UpdateInfo — for generic and github providers.
  autoUpdater.on('update-downloaded', (evt, info) => {
    mainWindow.webContents.send('update-downloaded');
  });

  ipcMain.once('update-now', () => {
    autoUpdater.quitAndInstall();
  });

  autoUpdater.checkForUpdates();
}
app.on('ready', autoUpdateConfig);
```

but at the end of the download, the event 'update-downloaded' is not being triggered.

Comment: I'm seeing the same thing. I do see a "Download completed to:" message in the electron logs but the `update-downloaded` event is not being emitted: `[electron] 2019-03-13 11:23:43.959 Electron[10005:966060] Download completed to: file:///Users/me/Library/Caches/com.github.electron.ShipIt/update.QPMDOoD/CNTRAL.Desktop-darwin-x64-0.1.2.zip`